# The selected project and billing account cannot pay for Maps in your region. Select an existing project that is paid for by a Maps billing account

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-console

This problem happens after enabling the billing method using a Pakistani Credit Card, and Billing details also fill up as Pakistani Addresses.

**The selected project and billing account cannot pay for Maps in your region. Select an existing project that is paid for by a Maps billing account.**

[image: Billing Error Problem]

I have this problem while creating a Flutter Application using Google Map SDK.

Comment: If you want to add images of your screen in the future; grabbing your phone, making a photograph, uploading that to your PC and then to Stack Overflow is a lot more involved than making a simple **screenshot**. Also the picture won't be distorted by bad focus, odd angles and the Moiré effect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Adriaan, Next time, I will fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

I have searched several sites and discovered that the problem is due to creating Pakistani Billing Addresses.

**Why does this problem happen?**

Google Cloud Console supports INR, USD and Rupee, but for using Google Map SDK / Enabling Map Billing, the account has to be USD Support.

**How to solve this ?**

First of all, check if you've enabled the API you're trying to use, or second, you must check the billing account type, go to an overview of your billing account, and there you'll find it. If it is a cloud console type, then you've to create another project and link it with another billing account with maps (that's what I've done, and still trying to find a way to merge both of them) and, most importantly, maps billing account won't in INR it'll be USD, The INR is allowed only of cloud console billing account not on Maps Platform.

Thanks to [incrediblezayed](https://www.reddit.com/user/incrediblezayed/) for sharing this on Reddit. If you want to know more, you can check this Reddit post. [Check Here ->](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/kwdc5x/flutter_google_maps_the_selected_project_and/)